What libraries do I need for PostGIS GEOGRAPHY to handle latitude and longitude?
I'm trying create a Geography (not geometry) service with Postgis. I know there are geometry answers/questions that are associated with the same error (e.g., this one that uses org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point; a geometry library) . However, I am interested in a Geography solution. As you can see in the flyway migration below, I am using a geography type and later on in my CityService I use latitude and longitude to create the location for cities. I've tried various combinations of libraries but have not been able to make it work. This was the closest I came until I got this endian error. What libraries do I need to use?
These are the technologies I'm using

Spring 3.2.5
Postgis db 16.2
Java 17
Hibernate 6.4
Flyway

V5__add_location_to_city.sql (Flyway migration)

ALTER TABLE city ADD location geography(point);


City.java
package com.mm.geoapp.model.db.geo;

import com.mm.geoapp.model.db.BaseModel;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
// import org.geolatte.geom.Point;
// import org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PGGeometryJdbcType;
// import org.springframework.data.geo.Point;
// import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point;

// import net.postgis.jdbc.geometry.Point;
// import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point;
import net.postgis.jdbc.PGgeometry;


@Entity
@Table(name = "city")
public class City extends BaseModel {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    //@Column(name = "location", nullable = true, columnDefinition = "geography(Point,4326)")
    @Column(name = "location", nullable = true)
    private PGgeometry location;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "state_region_id")
    private StateRegion stateRegion;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public PGgeometry getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(PGgeometry location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public StateRegion getStateRegion() {
        return stateRegion;
    }

    public void setStateRegion(StateRegion stateRegion) {
        this.stateRegion = stateRegion;
    }
}



CityService.java
package com.mm.geoapp.service;

import com.mm.geoapp.model.db.geo.City;
import com.mm.geoapp.model.db.geo.StateRegion;
import com.mm.geoapp.repository.CityRepository;
import net.postgis.jdbc.PGgeometry;
import net.postgis.jdbc.geometry.Point;
// import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class CityService {
    private final CityRepository cityRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CityService(CityRepository cityRepository) {
        this.cityRepository = cityRepository;
    }

    public City saveCityWithLocation(City city, Double latitude, Double longitude) {
        Point point = new Point(latitude, longitude);
        PGgeometry location = new PGgeometry(point);
        city.setLocation(location);
        return cityRepository.save(city);
    }
}


pom.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mm</groupId>
    <artifactId>geoapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>geoapp</name>
    <description>New MM</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-docker-compose</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.postgis</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgis-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2023.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-testcontainers</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>



application.properties
spring.application.name=geoapp

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:8008/postgis
spring.datasource.username=*****
spring.datasource.password=*****
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

Error
Hibernate: update city set location=?,name=?,state_region_id=? where id=?
2024-04-27T11:41:59.423-07:00  WARN 7664 --- [geoapp] [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: XX000
2024-04-27T11:41:59.423-07:00 ERROR 7664 --- [geoapp] [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: Invalid endian flag value encountered.
2024-04-27T11:41:59.432-07:00  INFO 7664 --- [geoapp] [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-04-27T11:41:59.433-07:00  INFO 7664 --- [geoapp] [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute statement [ERROR: Invalid endian flag value encountered.] [update city set location=?,name=?,state_region_id=? where id=?]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:341)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:241)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:566)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:794)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:676)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:426)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:164)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy104.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.mm.geoapp.service.CityService.saveCityWithLocation(CityService.java:44)
    at com.mm.geoapp.GeoappApplication.main(GeoappApplication.java:103)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement [ERROR: Invalid endian flag value encountered.] [update city set location=?,name=?,state_region_id=? where id=?]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.mutation.internal.AbstractMutationExecutor.performNonBatchedMutation(AbstractMutationExecutor.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.mutation.internal.MutationExecutorSingleNonBatched.performNonBatchedOperations(MutationExecutorSingleNonBatched.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.mutation.internal.AbstractMutationExecutor.execute(AbstractMutationExecutor.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.mutation.UpdateCoordinatorStandard.doStaticUpdate(UpdateCoordinatorStandard.java:778)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.mutation.UpdateCoordinatorStandard.performUpdate(UpdateCoordinatorStandard.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.mutation.UpdateCoordinatorStandard.coordinateUpdate(UpdateCoordinatorStandard.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2810)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:632)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:499)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1403)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2319)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:1976)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:439)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: Invalid endian flag value encountered.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2713)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2401)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:368)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:498)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:415)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:190)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:152)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:194)
    ... 38 more

